# Xcode version problems. error:using bridging headers with module interfaces is unsupported Command CompileSwiftSources failed with a nonzero exit code

Tags: objective-c, build, compiler-errors

my iPhone just upgraded and now my iOS version is 15.3.1. Since my old version(12.4) of Xcode doesn't support that version of OS, I've installed newer version of Xcode(13.2.1). Now I cannot run my project and I got this error. I've changed Build Libraries for Distribution to NO and than my build is successful but when I set up breakpoint and start debagging I'm losing connection with debugger on my iPhone. Also I put device file(15.0) in /Aplications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport and in Supporting Files but it didn't
help. I will appreciate any help. Best regards.

Answer (score 11):

Open your XCode,
Go to the Runner under PROJECTS -> search for 'distribution'

Make "Build Libraries for Distribution" to NO (if it is YES, change it to NO).

Do the same for Runner under TARGETS.

I also had the same problem I resolved it in this way.

[image: Runner]
[image: Runner]

**Update:**
Also don't forget to uncomment the following in iOS -> Podfile

```
platform :ios, '11.0'
```

Comment: Fixed the error for me when building for Flutter 3.3.9